# Drupal 7 Browser specific css

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-7, browser-detection

How can i have a browser specific css in Drupal 7 . I would like to load chrome.css if browser is chrome . Please help

Comment: Other than IE<9, what do you need browser-specific stylesheets for?

Comment: @Spudley :I need browser-specific css only for chrome

Comment: really? what particular feature?

Comment: @Spudley : i have set left:100px to a css element. The alignment is perfect in IE 8 and firefox 4 but in chrome i have to set left:350px

Comment: That sounds very odd. Chrome has excellent standards compliance, so I'm very surprised to hear something as fundamental as basic positioning is so badly out. I'd suspect there's something more to this; some other error in your stylesheet which needs to be fixed. I would advise you to look for the cause of the problem rather than trying to fix the symptoms with a hack. If you really can't find it, show us the code here (probably best in a new question), and I'm sure someone will point it out very quickly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this in your template.php file with a [preprocess_html](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) theme hook and [drupal_add_css](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) function.

You will find example in drupal 7 theme, for example in bartik :

```
// Add conditional stylesheets for IE
drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/css/ie.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'browsers' => array('IE' => 'lte IE 7', '!IE' => FALSE), 'preprocess' => FALSE));
drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/css/ie6.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'browsers' => array('IE' => 'IE 6', '!IE' => FALSE), 'preprocess' => FALSE));
```

Edit : since there are no *conditional comments* for chrome, you can check $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] :

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
    && stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'chrome')!==false) {
    drupal_add_css( ... );
}
```

But before doing this, **try to fix your css rules** !

Comment: But like Spudley said, before doing this you should try to **fix your css rules**.

Comment: it adds conditional css for IE how do i do it for chrome?

Comment: Well, since there is no conditional comments for chrome, you just have to check $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the [Conditional Stylesheets module](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_styles)

> Internet Explorer implements a proprietary technology called
>   Conditional Comments. While web developers frown upon technologies
>   that aren't cross-browser supported, many CSS developers have found
>   Conditional Comments very useful. They can have cleaner CSS in their
>   normal stylesheets and can fix the broken rendering in IE by placing
>   IE-only CSS inside conditional comments; this technique is even
>   recommended by Microsoft.
>   Without this module, the only way to have IE conditional stylesheets
>   was to add 37 lines of code (more if you want to add more than one
>   stylesheet) in four horribly-difficult-to-remember function calls to
>   your theme's template.php. Blech. Who wants that?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous speakers, you should absolutely try to change your css so that does not need browser specific code, but if you really need to target the Webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari) you can have a look at this solution:

http://www.evotech.net/blog/2010/04/hack-for-webkit-filter-for-chrome-and-safari/

It is not specific to Drupal, but a so-so accepted way of targeting webkit, in case of emergency.