# Drupal opera conditional-stylesheet

Tags: css, drupal, opera

in my attempts to add a custom stylesheet for the Opera browser I added the followinf line in the theme .info file:

```
conditional-stylesheets[if Opera][all][] = style-opera.css
```

The CSS file is uploaded to the server but the changes did not take.

I attempted a more direct route and added the following line to page.tpl.php:

```
  {[if Opera]>
```

{link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/sites/all/themes/zen/zen_newbuild/style-opera.css?" /}

NOTE: I had to deliberately leave out the html comment features so the code is visible here

Still no change.

Am I doning something wrong?

Comment: There are Opera conditional comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional comments is a IE feature.

But you will find here a lot of answers for your question :
[Drupal 7 Browser specific css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883140/drupal-7-browser-specific-css)

...etc