# Vertical Scrollbar not displaying in IE7/6 in Drupal website?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drupal, scroll

I have a Drupal site, but I have found an issue in Internet Explorer 7 and 6 where a vertical scrollbar is not displaying. I added the code below to the style.css file in the theme, but with no luck. Is there another workaround?

```
html {
       overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Edit: removed the code overflow code above, here's the current html/body code: (I just now specified the height)

```
html {

}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, "Bitstream Vera Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 75%;
  height: 100%; margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Could you post more CSS? Specifically, any `#wrapper`, `html` or `body` styles.

Comment: try specifying overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;

Comment: Your CSS for IE6 should be `* { display: none; }` ;)

Comment: A good place to start is fixing your validation errors: [validator.w3.org speeddawg results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fspeeddawg.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link to the website or the css on the troubling? Is difficult to answer with the info provided. When I have problems like this my normal approach is creating a browser specific css which can save you a lot of time. To do it in drupal 7 here is an example I took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883140/drupal-7-browser-specific-css)

```
drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/css/ie.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'browsers' => array('IE' => 'lte IE 7', '!IE' => FALSE), 'preprocess' => FALSE));
drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/css/ie6.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'browsers' => array('IE' => 'IE 6', '!IE' => FALSE), 'preprocess' => FALSE));
```

I find that it's normally easier to fix those kind of errors with IE Developers Tools and a browser specific stylesheet.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The website is https://speeddawg.com/ - Thank you for the help! The problem was fixed in IE6 with the `height: 100%; margin-bottom: 1px;` code.